# hello world booting using raspberry pi B+

Tags: boot

today I bought raspberry pi B+

unfortunately my 16 sd card lost and can't buy another one before 2 day

I have 512 Mb Sd card

I need to test my raspberry on tv so is there any simple boot program like hello world to show it on tv

I google it but maybe I have no correct keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://liliputing.com/2014/05/picore-5-3-linux-25mb-operating-system-raspberry-pi.html

It's 25mb and does a whole lot more then hello world.

EDIT: Another important thing to note: "Tiny Core is designed to run entirely in RAM, which means that you don’t install it so much as load the disk image onto an SD card. When you’re running the operating system, everything is loaded into the computer’s memory."

Comment: a big big thaks, you made my day  :)